# RequireJS - include a JS library without defining it in a particular module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm looking at using [Formalize](http://formalize.me/) in a project. To do this I simply need to include the .js file in the build (either in the head or before the closing body tag). How would I do this using RequireJS? As far as I'm aware, the libraries I'm currently using are all defined in certain modules, for example, when using [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel) I have to set up options and initialise the carousel, so I have a carousel.js file which defines the use of this library, therefore including it in the build.

```
define(['owlcarousel'], function() {

    var $ = jQuery,
        $carousel = $('.homepage-hero');

    return {

        init: function() {
            if($carousel.length >= 1) {
                this.setUp();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },

        setUp: function() {
            this.initCarousel();
        },

        initCarousel: function() {
            $carousel.owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                loop: true, 
                nav:true,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 500,
                dotsSpeed: 500,
                paginationSpeed: 500
            }); 
        }

    };

});
```

But with Formalize I don't need to do anything with it, just include it. This is my main.js file which configures require and my libraries.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/wp-content/themes/test/library/js/libs',
    paths: {
        base: '../',
        onmediaquery: 'onmediaquery.min',
        owlcarousel: 'owl.carousel.min',
        simpleweather: 'jquery.simpleWeather.min',
        formalize: 'jquery.formalize'
    }
});

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        require(['base/bootstrap']);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And here is my bootstrap.js which organises my modules.

```
require(['base/responsive', 'base/carousel', 'base/equal-heights', 'base/weather'],
    function(responsive, carousel, equal_heights, weather) {

            var $ = jQuery;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                //Prevent FOUC
                $('body').css('display', 'block');

                carousel.init();
                equal_heights.init();
                weather.init();

                responsive.init();

            });
    }
);
```